# Calculate edge of right triangle, two edges given

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

Given two coordinates of a right triangle's leg/cathetus' edges (x0,y0),(x1,y1) and the length of the other leg/cathetus (L). How do I calculate the coordinates of the remaining edge depending on x0,y0,x1,y1 and L?

Comment: Is the right angle at $(x_0,y_0)$ or $(x_1,y_1)$? In any case, there are two possibilities for $(x_2,y_2)$.

Comment: the right angle is at (x1,y1) and yes, there are two possibiites. How do I calculate them?

Comment: A general formula is horrendously complicated and unlikely to be helpful. Label the points $P_0,P_1,P_2$. The idea is that you want $P_1P_2$ perpendicular to $P_0P_1$ and $P_1P_2^2=L^2$. You can express the first condition either by finding the gradient of $P_0P_1=k$ say and taking the gradient of $P_1P_2$ as $-\frac{1}{k}$ or by taking the dot product as 0, ie $x_2(x_1-x_0)+y_2(y_1-y_0)=x_1(x_1-x_0)+y_1(y_1-y_0)=0$. As usual $P_1P_2^2=(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$A = (x_0, y_0),\ B = (x_1, y_1),\ a = BC,\ b = AC,\ c = AB$

Let's say that the vertex at at $A = (x_0, y_0)$.

The vector $\overrightarrow{AB}$ is $B-A = \langle x_1 - x_0, y_1 - y_0 \rangle$

Point $C$  will be the endpoint of the vector
$\pm \dfrac{a}{c}\overrightarrow{AB_\perp}$ where
$\overrightarrow{AB_\perp} = \langle y_0-y_1, x_1 - x_0 \rangle$

So $C = (x_0, y_0) \pm \dfrac
{L}{\sqrt{(x_1-x_0)^2+(y_1-y_0)^2}}
(y_0-y_1, x_1 - x_0)$

Note that, depending on your choice of $A$ and $B$ and your choice of $\pm$, there are four possibilities for the position of $C$.